# data export error mysql workbench 6.3

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to export the whole database using workbench. I keep getting the following error message. I used `server>data export` option in workbench.
[image]

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug in MySQL Workbench 6.3.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/wb-news-6-3-5.html). Your options are to either (A) wait for an upcoming Workbench version to fix it, or (B) change your mysqldump binary (under User Preferences) to a different non-bundled mysqldump binary, likely one from MySQL Server 5.6.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try option B.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily dump the whole database from the command line:

```
mysqldump -u <db_username> -p -h <db_host> db_name > database_dump.sql
```